# Ubuntu 15.10 (seemingly) randomly crashing requiring reboot

Tags: crash, 15.10

Every so often (often enough that it's annoying) my screen goes black and then shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdN9f.jpg) (sorry for the quality).

The only way I know how to get it working again is to reboot my laptop. Is there a way to stop this from happening or of resolving the problem without a reboot?